# Does Dot Net Framework use any of the java components?

Tags: asp.net

Does dot net framework or com components use any of java components?
For ex:- java beans, java applets, java servlets etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

It never has. It is all either C/C++ (for the runtime, jitter etc...) or .NET directly.

Comment: Here is a text from wikipedia com topic
 COM is very similar to other component software interface technologies, such as CORBA and Java Beans, although each has its own strengths and weaknesses

Comment: @sly_Chandan - `similar != same`. It also doesn't mean that they use each other. Sure, using a bridge you could communicate between them (like iKvm does), but why would MS ever try to start off with integrating Java into its internal framework? That would introduce some dependency on Sun, one of its major competitors.